# Stripe payments routes charging the same for different charge buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to add two buttons to my payment platform. But stripe is charging me the same amount even when the other button is pressed. This is my attempt but it isn't working. I am not sure what is going wrong.

## charges_controller.rb

```
def create

  # Amount in cents - €1000.00
  @amount = 100000

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :email => params[:stripeEmail],
    :source  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :customer    => customer.id,
    :amount      => @amount,
    :description => 'Thanks, on behalf of CMRF',
    :currency    => 'eur'
  )

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  flash[:error] = e.message
  redirect_to new_charge_path
end
```

## View

```
<%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'chargeForm' do %>
          <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail' %>
          <button id="customButton" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Sponsor a Hole</button>

          <script>
            var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
              key: '<%= ENV["PUBLISHABLE_KEY"] %>',
              token: function(token, args) { 
                document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token.id;
                document.getElementById("stripeEmail").value = token.email;
                document.getElementById("chargeForm").submit();
              }
            });

            document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
              // Open Checkout with further options
              handler.open({
                name: 'My Company',
                description: 'Entry (€1000.00)',
                currency: 'eur',
                amount: 100000,
                billingAddress: true,
              });
              e.preventDefault();
            });
          </script>
        <% end %>


<%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'chargeForm1' do %>
          <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail' %>
          <button id="customButton1" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Enter A Team</button>

          <script>
            var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
              key: '<%= ENV["PUBLISHABLE_KEY"] %>',
              // image: '/assets/my_logo.png',
              token: function(token, args) { 
                document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token.id;
                document.getElementById("stripeEmail").value = token.email;
                document.getElementById("chargeForm").submit();
              }
            });

            document.getElementById('customButton1').addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
              // Open Checkout with further options
              handler.open({
                name: 'My Company',
                description: 'Sponsor (€200.00)',
                currency: 'eur',
                amount: 20000,
                billingAddress: true,
                // shippingAddress: true
              });
              e.preventDefault();
            });
          </script>
        <% end %>
```

## Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :charges

  root 'pages#index'
  get 'pages/about'
  get 'pages/contact'
  get 'pages/pay'
```

Comment: The first issue I found is, for both handlers you have taken `document.getElementById("chargeForm").submit();`  but no `chargeForm1` for the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The `amount` and `currency` parameters that you pass to [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) (in the call to `handler.open(...)`) are used for display purposes only.

The actual amount and currency that are used for the charge are the ones you provide in the `amount` and `currency` parameters of the [charge creation request](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) that is sent by your backend code.

In this case, the charge is created in your `charges_controller.rb` file, and the amount is fixed. If you want to charge different amounts, you'd need to send some other field along with the token so that your backend code can know which amount to charge.

Unless the amount is explicitly set by the customer (e.g. if you're accepting donations), you should not rely on an amount that is provided by the customer's browser as it would be very easy to change it. Instead, you likely want to use some identifier that you can use in your backend code to retrieve the correct amount.

Comment: I would be using the controller to set the amount, the amount above is just to ensure the user knows how much they are paying. But in terms of using 2 buttons, would I need to set up a new controller for each button?